# What do you use to monitor jscript memory usage in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt, memory-management

We're debugging a GWT app. Runs ok in Firefox, in IE6.0 starts working ok but after some time, it gets on its knees and starts to crawl.
After doing some tests we're suspecting some memory problems  ( too much memory used, memory leaks, etc )
Besides using taskmanager and processxp to watch the memory usage grow :)....¿do you recommend any other memory monitoring tool?

Like jprobe for jscript? :)

Comment: Is jprobe giving you conflicting reports with respect to Task Manager?

Comment: The last sentence was ment as a joke, I used jprobe in the past to profile a Java app, so now I'd need something like a jprobe for IE jscript. I really don't know if such a thing exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered the similar question earlier regarding JS memory leak detection in IE[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469841/how-to-check-if-memory-leak-occurs-when-removing-an-element-out-of-dom/1470092#1470092)

these are the tools am using

- [sIEve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/)
- [IEJSLeaksDetector2.0.1.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/gpde/pages/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ieleak/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Drip](http://outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Main_Page), with pretty good results.

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using "sIEve": http://home.wanadoo.nl/jsrosman/

At the moment I'm using it to see how many bytes IE allocates ( and deallocates ) in response to user activity ( user opens a menu, GWT executes some javascript, IE allocates memory ).

I also tried these other tools but I don't have any conclusions yet
http://blogs.msdn.com/gpde/pages/javascript-memory-leak-detector.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en

Comment: The second link is broken, the URL currently working is http://blogs.msdn.com/gpde/pages/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2.aspx