# How to check if memory leak occurs when removing an element out of DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

```
<div id="target">
...

</div>
```

$('#target').html('') will remove the content,but how to check if the listeners or anything else that holds memory is removed at the same time?

Comment: As JavaScript is garbage-collected, the objects probably aren't removed from memory exactly at that time - there's just a promise that they will be, eventually. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Standard JavaScript defines no means to instrument the interpreter's garbage collector, so I don't think this is possible.

However, since removing nodes is not an uncommon operation, I would not worry about browsers leaking memory in this case. Indeed as Piskvor said, the memory is probably not released immediately, but when the garbage collector eventually runs.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you can detect a leak within a JavaScript (using JavaScript). but there are tools available to detect the leaks in JavaScript

- [sIEve](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626143559/http://home.orange.nl:80/jsrosman/)
- [IEJSLeaksDetector2.0.1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gpde/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this, but since you're using jQuery you should use `$('#target').empty()`. This detaches all event handlers before removing the child elements. When these are collected is up to the browser, but this ensures that they will get collected when the time comes. You can also use `$.remove()` to get rid of the selected element and all children.

http://api.jquery.com/empty